# I created a virtual assistant, everything was fine but now after I installed an api, my music function is not able to get the location

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, project

I created a virtual assistant music was played before, after I installed an api "zolframalpha", error occurred in playing music I attached the code with the error

error is:

```
line 1 :-----File "C:\Users\Hari Prakash\Desktop\siri\main.py", line 62, in playMusic      os.startfile(location+musics[0]) 

line2:--------- FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Hari Prakash\\Desktop\\siri\\musics//wolframalpha.cpython-37.pyc'
```

```
def playMusic(self):
    self.speak('Playing Music Please Wait')
    musics = [x for x in os.walk(os.getcwd())][-1][-1]
    shuffle(musics)
    location = os.path.join(
        os.getcwd(),
        "musics//"  
    )
    os.startfile(location+musics[0])
    print(musics)
    self.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
musics = [x for x in os.walk(os.getcwd())][-1][-1]
```

gets a list of files in the last subdirectory in the current working directory

Assuming your music is located in the "musics" folder of your current working directory, you can reorder your code like so and change the line for `musics =`

```py
def playMusic(self):
    self.speak('Playing Music Please Wait')
    location = os.path.join(
        os.getcwd(),
        "musics//"  
    )
    # get all files in musics location
    musics = [x for x in os.listdir(location) if os.path.isfile(location + x)]
    shuffle(musics)

    os.startfile(location+musics[0])
    print(musics)
    self.main()
```